# How to access/share ubuntu app files in windows

Tags: windows, files

I am using a computer that has Ubuntu app installed on Windows 11

when I open Ubuntu I can see there are files and folders
I tried to get access these files from windows but I don't know where they are in windows

here is an example

```
(base) asmgx@DELLG3:~$ ls
Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh  Downloads  Public     anaconda3                               mnt
Desktop                            Music      Templates  auto-sklearn                            thinclient_drives
Documents                          Pictures   Videos     google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb  winhome
(base) asmgx@DELLG3:~$
```

Folders Desktop and Download are not the same as my Windows Desktop and Download

Any idea how can I find these folders and files?

Comment: Try searching windows files for asmgx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are files saved when created in a WSL terminal window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194395/where-are-files-saved-when-created-in-a-wsl-terminal-window)